# The license footer says that attribution is required when using the content and that attribution is required

Tags: bug, status-completed, footer

The current license footer states the following:

> site design / logo © 2014 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required

Yes, it is a very minor detail, but "CC BY-SA" already states that attribution is required, and repeating it felt odd the moment I saw it. It's like saying "we've got a CD and a compact disc, too!".

Is it by design that it repeats that?

Comment: I suppose putting it in brackets would show it was pulling out an important detail rather than adding detail

Comment: I don't think it was done deliberately on purpose.

Comment: Being expressly explicit and overly repetitive can be an easy way to simply remind people about the required attribution requirement.

Comment: Right.  It never hurts to repeat the obvious, especially when you see that it's apparently not so obvious to some folks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I can understand that...but can it be done in a "correct" way then?

Comment: Sure it can: *site design / logo © 2014 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 **with attribution required** (yes, we know it already says that in the license, but we thought we'd repeat it here for emphasis because, well, y'know, we think it's important.)*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I was more thinking about fixing "... licensed under Creative Commons - Attribution Required - Share Alike with Attribution Required" into something like "... licensed under CC-BY-SA; Creative Commons, Attribution Required".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the changes in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347758/creative-commons-licensing-ui-and-data-updates) roll out, this will no longer be an issue:

> 3. Footer text, other references:
>      [...]
>
>    2. Text requiring attribution is no longer written. This is implicit from the definition of the “BY” section of the license name.