# Stack Exchange Data Dumps still indicating old attribution requirements

Tags: bug, data-dump, legal, licensing, creative-commons

The [Stack Exchange Data Dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) still contain wording mandating that attribution be given in specific ways, going beyond the Creative Commons licensing requirements:

> Specifically the attribution requirements are as follows:
>   ...

As pointed out originally in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347758/creative-commons-licensing-ui-and-data-updates), and as eventually addressed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347758/creative-commons-licensing-ui-and-data-updates), these requirements are going away: "Text requiring attribution is no longer written".

Is this an oversight? Would it be possible to remove this text too?

Comment: Let me also point out that the license indicated in the dumps is CC-BY-SA 4.0, even though it was eventually admitted that older content is not under that version of the license.