# Rollback of a post to a revision with an older license version does not make the post relate to that older license version

Tags: bug, status-declined, licensing, rollbacks

A month ago it was noticed that a rollback *could* [change the license version backwards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347762/389297).

In [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347758/creative-commons-licensing-ui-and-data-updates#comment1163698_347762), it was noted by Yaakov Ellis that the license version on a post *should* relate to the license version related to the current (displayed) revision of the post (so a rollback to an older post revision might downgrade the license version).

But currently, the license version on a post relates to the date of the last change, which is a bug or wrong feature.

---

Example from a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347781/389297) by DavidPostill:

[image: example]

The rollback to Revision 3 does not change the license to CC BY-SA 3.0

---

In the same comment by Yaakov Ellis is was mentioned that a fix for this case was pending review.

Because it has not been fixed yet I thought about making it a separate question.

Comment: The post you linked to by me was specifically about to **tag only edits**. That has indeed been fixed (and just confirmed as fixed by me).

Comment: Can you please link to a post where this happened?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/331983/timeline

Comment: I see now that it is probably because that is a deleted post. I notice that it doesn't occur in other posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "error" occurred with a [deleted answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/331983/timeline).  By re-rolling back to the revision it got to the correct version. I consider this no big deal and a sufficient workaround.

Comment: The backfill correcting this for old content ignored deleted posts