# Why aren't tag edits and comments licensed as CC BY-SA 4.0 in post timelines?

Tags: discussion, tags, comments, licensing, timeline

[E.g.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/posts/116070/timeline):

[image]

Why aren't tag edits and comments licensed as CC BY-SA 4.0 in post timelines?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The CC BY-SA license only covers [content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing). Tags are (apparently) considered metadata. In the [original implementation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347781/295232), they triggered a license change, but after the bug report, they no longer do (and I agree with that, FWIW).

Comments *are* licensed under various CC BY-SA licenses, depending on when they were posted. At least [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/295232) and the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/comment) can tell you the license of a specific comment. You can also hover over the timestamp:

[image]

Including that information in the timeline *might* confuse users, thinking that the license of the comment would apply to the post as well. After all, it's the timeline of the *post*, and comments are second-class citizens, so they get less love than questions and answers.

Comment: I think that the content should not differentiate between data and metadata. Tags are just part of the content and fall under the same license since they are supplied by the user. But then I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks, feature request:  [Tags assigned to a question should be CC BY-SA licensed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367065/178179)