# Show license info for tag excerpts and wikis explicitly

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki, licensing, tag-wiki-excerpt

All user contributions on Stack Exchange are licensed (currently under CC-BY-SA 4.0). Back in 2020, [Creative Commons Licensing UI and Data Updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347758/creative-commons-licensing-ui-and-data-updates) made a change in showing the license explicitly for Q&A posts (on the timeline and share pop-up) and comments (on the tooltip). However, the UI for tag excerpts and wikis is not touched.

On the other hand, Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) actually shows the license info for both tag excerpts and wikis, considering those are also considered "posts" in the database.

> The following tables available on data.stackexchange.com will include (in the next refresh) a ContentLicense field: `Posts`, `PostHistory` and `Comments`.

[SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1655417) (thanks [Larnu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420829/2821954)!):

```sql
SELECT T.TagName,
       T.[Count],
       W.Body AS Wiki,
       W.ContentLicense AS WikiLicence,
       E.Body AS Excerpt,
       E.ContentLicense AS ExcerptLicence
FROM dbo.Tags T
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Posts W ON T.WikiPostId = W.Id
                          AND W.PostTypeId = 5
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Posts E ON T.ExcerptPostId = E.Id
                          AND E.PostTypeId = 4
--Where [Count]>10
ORDER BY Count DESC;
```

[An answer by muru](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347794/241919) to the announcement also raised this issue, which has been status reviewed but not handled yet:

> What about tag wikis and excerpts? They are also (usually) contributed by users, and can be revised. However, at present there are no generally-accessible timelines for tag wikis (e.g., https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/168600/timeline) or excerpts (e.g., https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/168601/timeline) [...]

Thus, can we have the license info shown for tag excerpts and wikis, at least as simple as a single line of text directly on the tag info page?

Comment: A couple of interesting use cases that are related [licensing of retags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367065/) and [licensing of translations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382629).