# CC BY-SA in footer should be capitalized

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, footer, creative-commons

The footer currently has **cc by-sa** written in small case but it should be capitalized as **CC BY-SA** following the style used in the official [Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) page, the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), and one of the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347758) posts.

[image: screenshot of CC BY-SA license in site's footer]

Also, if anyone's wondering:

- **CC** stands for *Creative Commons*.
- **BY** stand for *by*, as in: *"All of our licenses require that users provide attribution **(BY)** to the creator"*.
- **SA** stands for *"ShareAlike **(SA)**, which requires adaptations of the material be released under the same license"*.

Comment: Ideally, this should be changed _everywhere_ that it is currently lowercase.  This includes, at least, the image upload dialog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All instances of "CC BY-SA" text appearing on the site (including in the Stacks Editor) are now in upper-case.

> CC BY-SA
> now with only capital
> letters everywhere

Comment: I just noticed that the footer of [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) is still using an older revision of the footer, and has cc by-sa in lowercase.

Comment: Area 51 still has it in lowercase as well (though that's sort of expected at this point :P).